# How to let search bar disappear immediately when moving to another VC

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

Below Gif is from my app, the 1st VC includes a search bar to filter the songs, and when press a row to transition to 2nd VC to show selected playing song.

**The question** here is that when 2nd VC is opened, the search bar is not disappeared immediately, it has like 1 or 2 seconds delay, could see that behavior from below GIF.

/ / / Here is my code, how could I solve this issue? Any hint is appreciate.

- The search bar

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
...
// add search bar
        resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            // set search Bar covered color, same with tableView's background color.
            controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x292f33)
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

            return controller
            })() // closure, learn it later!!
...
}
```

- I set search bar to disabled state when leaving current VC.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)

        resultSearchController.isActive = false
    }
```

[image]

/ / / Update, as matt's comment, I change the code to integrate search bar into navigation bar, and now the search bar is disappear immediately after opening VC2.

remove `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar` and integrate the search bar into the nav bar `navigationItem.searchController = resultSearchController`. Now the behavior is same as Apple's inbox app.

Comment: First fix the issue with your nav bar. Then put the search bar in the nav bar.

Comment: @matt, so what is the issue in the navigation bar? Could you point out it more specifically?

Comment: Nav bar has gap at top. The blue should stretch up behind the status bar.

Comment: So just set your `navigationItem.searchController` and everything will work correctly.

Comment: put resultSearchController.isActive = false in viewwill appear not in disappear

Comment: @Ali Xhah, the searchBar is used in 1st VC, if set ```resultSearchController.isActive = false``` in ```viewWillAppear```, then that searchBar will be never used. I want it to be disappeared in 2nd VC but not on 1st VC.

Comment: @matt, thanks for your reply. However, I still not get your point. For me, I set ```self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar``` in the code to set tableHeaderView as the searchBar, is that not enough? Then would you show your code ```navigationItem.searchController``` with some context.

Comment: I'm saying try putting it in the nav bar instead of using it as the table header view. This is the interface that iOS now expects, so you should get a smooth transition to the next view controller. If you don't want to try that, fine. But it's a suggestion and it costs you nothing to give it a try.

Comment: @matt, finally I get where to put that code in. I do want to try, I just didn't know where to put that line of code ```navigationItem.searchController``` before. Well it could includes the search bar in the nav bar after implement that code. But it is not what I want, it couldn't filter the tableView now. And more than that I want the search bar behind the Navi Bar. Also I see other thread said that after iOS11 should use ```navigationItem.searchController```.

Comment: "But it is not what I want, it couldn't filter the tableView now" Why couldn't you? Nothing else about how the search controller works needs to change. Look at Apple's Mail app. Go to the Inbox and pull down to see the search field. It is in the navigation bar. This is the interface Apple expects you to use. It works for them so why not use it?

Comment: @matt, comparing to the inbox app of iPhone, you are correct, I change my code to integrate the search bar into the nav bar. Before I look to some apps in app store, and refer to them's layout. But they may be out of date now.

Answer (score 0):

```
searchController.searchBar.isHidden = false
```

Hiding the searchController instead of making the active state to false may solve your issue.

Try adding in the above line to your code in viewWillDisappear()

hopefully this helps.

Comment: I had tried this before, it will hide the navigation bar together, so the result will be search bar & navigation bar both hidden:( I didn't mention this in my question.

Comment: you should remove your searchbar from the navigation, put the search bar on that page view, not the navigation

Comment: Actually, it is not a page view but a tableView to present music songs below navigation bar. For the layout looking well, I want put that below the nav bar and above the tableView. Well, currently it is already separated from the navigation bar. Just don't know how to remove the delay of search bar disappear in 2nd VC.